# Conditional regex in.net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to write a Regex for an expression that matches below inputs

```
Eat : True Sleep : True
Eat : True Sleep : False
Eat : False Sleep : True
```

but fails

```
Eat : False Sleep : False
```

How can I put this condition in my Regex expression or is testing this in 2 regex patterns recommended?

Comment: So you want at least one of them to be true (logical OR)?

Comment: why not just match 'True' then?

Comment: Yes anyone of the 3 scenarios can be met. Just matching should fail for False and False.

Comment: Because True; False and False; true are also acceptable.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried.

Comment: If you need two conditions the use an OR (|) in the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the required regex

```
Eat.*True.*Sleep.*|Eat.*Sleep.*True
```

Comment: This will also match "Eat_ANYTHING_with_cheese_TrueSleepSHEEP" and "EatSleepTrue".

Comment: Yes, it will match it. I assumed that data will be of the same pattern as given in question

Answer (score 1):

```
Eat : True Sleep : (?:True|False)|Eat : False Sleep : (?!False)True
```

Could also be achieved with negative lookahead as above.

Comment: Can be more simply expressed as `Eat : True Sleep : (?:True|False)|Eat : False Sleep : True` no need for the negative lookahead